# Посоветуйте хорошие книги по тестированию?

Tags: книги, тестирование

Посоветуйте хорошие книги по тестированию?

Comment: Хоршо бы уточнить направление тестируемого софта.

Comment: А что можно для начала? тестами ни разу не занимался.. Ну например desktopные приложение и web.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другие учебные материалы по тестированию](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451404/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 1):

*Савин Роман - "Тестирование DOT COM или Пособие по жестокому обращению с багами в интернет-стартапах"* - очень хороша для начала!

Answer (score 1):

Например:
Лайза Криспин, Джанет Грегори
Гибкое тестирование. Практическое руководство для тестировщиков ПО и гибких команд