# Книги и другие учебные материалы по тестированию

Tags: книги, тестирование

В этом вопросе собирается литература по тестированию.

Формат:

> Имя Фамилия — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ г..

Формат для переведенной литературы:

> Имя Фамилия (Name Surname) — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ перевода ("Full name of the book", YYYY )

- Не создавайте новых ответов — редактируйте этот.
- Не размещайте ссылки на нелегальный контент вроде торрент-трекеров.
- Старайтесь сохранять разделение по категориям (когда они будут).
- Сохраняйте алфавитную (лексикографическую) сортировку по названию книги.

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Comment: Конечно. Сначала -- в произвольном, затем, когда будет много книг, появится деление на разделы.

Comment: А что должна дать алфавитная сортировка?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Книги

- Лайза Криспин, Джанет Грегори — «Гибкое тестирование. Практическое руководство для тестировщиков ПО и гибких команд»
- Гленфорд Майерс и др. — «Искусство тестирования программ» (The Art of Software Testing)
- Джеймс Уиттакер и Ко. — «Как тестируют в Google» («How Google Tests Software»)
- Кент Бек (Kent Beck) — «Разработка через тестирование» (Test-Driven Development by Example)
- Роман Савин — «Тестирование DOT COM или Пособие по жестокому обращению с багами в интернет-стартапах»
- Lee Copeland — «A Practitioner's Guide to Software Test Design»
- Серия книг «Pragmatic Unit Testing»
- Roy Osherove — «The art of unit testing»
- Сэм Канер, Джек Фолк, Енг Кек Нгуен — «Тестирование программного обеспечения»
- Джерард Мессарош — «Шаблоны тестирования xUnit»

## Лекции

- [Алексей Петров — Качество и тестирование ПО (Технопарк Mail.Ru Group)](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrCZzMib1e9pDKLsabJYuODdVJrHYc4Jd)
- [Школа автоматизации процессов разработки (Яндекс)](https://academy.yandex.ru/events/autoschool/spb-2014/)
- [Все лекции Яндекса о тестировании](https://events.yandex.ru/lib/talks/?audience=testirovschiki)

## Статьи

- [Robert C. Martin — Three rules of TDD](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd) (Ядро TDD)
- [Robert C. Martin — Untested code dark matter](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.UntestedCodeDarkMatter) (Проект без покрытия тестами как непрофессионализм)
- [Robert C. Martin — The little Mocked](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/14/TheLittleMocker.html) (Различия между Dummy, Stub, Spy, Mock, Fake)
- [Они пишут правильную вещь](https://kholeg.wordpress.com/2006/11/20/%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%8C/) (О тестировании ПО в космической отрасли)