# Как правильно протестировать парсер

Tags: c#, парсер

Пишу парсер вики-текста, текста, который генерирует html-текст. То есть определенные наборы символов должны преобразовываться в определенные html теги. Например текст `{{background:текст @color:red}}` 
преобразуется в `<span style="background-color:red;">набегов</span>`

Различных вики-тегов довольно много и теоретически их комбинирование может првести к непредвиденному поведению, которого хотелось бы избежать. Другими словами теги друг с другом из за ошибок в реализации парсера могут работать непправильно. Такие ошибки всплывают регулярно и чем больше разных тегов тем больше возможных комбинаций и ошибок. Я хотел бы это как то тестировать и отыскивать такие ошибки на этапе тестирования. Но не очень представляю как правильно протестировать этот парсер и как вообще написать такой тест. Можно попробовать написать некий "эталонный" html, который должен получаться при применении парсинга к некой вики-разметке и с которым сверять результат. Но этот вариант выглядит несколько неуклюжим. Подскажите если кто знает как все таки правильно будет протестировать этот самый парсер и как их вообще тестируют?

Comment: Зря вы используете слово "парсер" - потому что речь идет о трансляторе.

Comment: Судить со стороны "теоретически" - очень плохая привычка, в особенности на начальном этапе проекта. Это - та-же самая ранняя оптимизация, просто названная иначе. Вначале найдите практические проблемные ситуации - тогда и будете думать как их решать. А вообще, в вашей ситуации можно было бы заменить трансляцию на строгий парсинг - некорректные ситуации отсекались бы ещё на этапе построения синтаксического дерева..

Comment: _"теоретически их комбинирование может првести"_ -- теоретически может быть все что угодно и нужны fuzzy-тесты, но в реальности тест проверяет корректность работы определенного кода в определенной ситуации.

Comment: _"теги друг с другом из за ошибок в реализации парсера могут работать непправильно"_ -- можете привести пример неправильной работы тегов?

Answer (score 1):

Начните с простейших модульных тестов. Начните писать что-нибудь похожее на:

```
[TestFixture]
public class WikiParserTest
{
    private WikiParser parser;

    [SetUp]
    public void setUp()
    {
        this.parser = new WikiParser(ParsingRules.Instance);
    }
    [Test]
    public void background_parsing_test()
    {
        string wikiText = "{{background:текст @color:red}}";
        string expectedHtml = "<span style="background-color: red;">текст</span>";

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedHtml, this.parser.Parse(wikiText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Тест он на то и тест, что имитирует реальную ситуацию и проверяет "правильно ли ведёт себя код" в данной ситуации.

Соответственно как вариант общего теста для парсера можно взять некоторый "сложный" вход и "эталонный" выход.И прогоняя вход через парсер ожидать полного соответствия с выходом. Но вы ведь понимаете, что теги можете отрабатывать корректно, но где-то по вашей же задумке будет убираться один пробел и тест после этого уже будет провален. Т.е."эталонный выход" нужно будет периодически корректировать что не есть гуд т.к. по сути происходит "подгонка" результатов.

Ещё один минус эталонного теста - он не даёт представления о причинах провала теста. Т.е. для более детального отслеживания нужны будут тесты с небольшими кусками входных данных со "сложными" местами. Не прохождение такого теста сразу подскажет в чём проблема. Но! (и это важно) не подскажет на какое место в коде нужно обратить внимание в процессе исправления ошибки. Это вобщем-то не проблема, пока вы помните алгоритмы и хорошо ориентируетесь в логике своего кода (другими словами в состоянии "скомпилировать" свой код в уме и примерно прикинуть где возникает ошибка) но если так получится что вы на пару месяцев отвлечётесь от этого кода то потом чтобы что-то в нём поправить вам понадобиться ой как много времени...

Для грамотного покрытия кода тестами одного разнообразия и заковыристости тестов будет недостаточно. Нужна соответствующая архитектура тестируемого кода. Почитайте литературу по TDD и BDD (вот например [список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451404/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E) такой литературы). Поищите примеры кода с "хорошей" тестируемой архитектурой.